# PHP files not executing when placed in a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, modx

I'm trying to transfer a Wordpress website into a client's server. The existing website of the client is run in MODX (a php-based CMS). I have created a subdirectory in the root called "new" and put my Wordpress files in there so I can first install it there and if everything looks good, move it to the root.

However, the problem is that I can't run php files from that sub directory. Every time I navigate to a file, the browser downloads the file instead of running it. I can run files from the root just fine.

Anybody knows what the issue might be? Can something in the .htaccess prevent files from running from a sub directory?

Comment: sounds like security/sharing issue on the directory. right click it and select the prooper action under sharing or security tab (depending on the os).

Comment: .htaccess could, but it'd be very odd if it was.

Comment: @alfred: you presume the OP is running on a windows box...

Comment: It can be a wrong PHP version being set in an `.htacess` within the buggy sub directory. Check my answer below for more details. For you information, depending on the MODX version, it may be necessary to set PHP to version 5 to ensure the compatibility with some modules that were not ported to version 7. This is especially true for the Evolution branch (0.9x up to 1.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `.htaccess` file can prevent proper operation/access of PHP files in  your sub-directory. Try removing the `.htaccess` file completely and report the results.

I have seen this issue with bogus `.htaccess` files.

Comment: You might have broken friendly urls on the MODX site by doing this - it needs the .htaccess file

Comment: The point is that there is something wrong with the .htaccess file and now he has a good starting point for coming to a full resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Do not rename the `.htaccess` or delete it. The best way is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40) where it suggest to make the edits in `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Among possible other reasons, the presence of an `.htacess` file within your subdirectory can typically cause the issue, especially if it sets a different PHP version than the one in use on your server.

---

I recently had similar issue when trying to port to PHP 7, some site that was in production using PHP 5.

Checking that the problem is only for a specific subfolder and not for all subfolders:

> ```
> http://localhost/my-host-site/phpinfo.php  // showed PHP version as 7.1
> http://localhost/my-host-site/new_folder/phpinfo.php  // showed PHP version as 7.1
> http://localhost/my-host-site/buggy_folder/phpinfo.php // NOT WORKING
> ```

In the buggy subfolder, the PHP code was not interpreted.

I had a look within the subfolder ; there was an `.htacess` file and its content was:

```
#PHP 5.6 : 
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php56
</FilesMatch>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

I had completely forgotten that file, which was in use to force the remote server using PHP 5.6. On the local server, it prevented PHP 7.1 to be called to intepret the file.